# Where does the \par come from with \hbox:n

Tags: expl3

I don't know anything about expl3. I naively thought that I would get the same output for both lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
A \def\par{1\global\let\par\@@par\par} \hbox{B} C

A \def\par{1\global\let\par\@@par\par} \ExplSyntaxOn\hbox:n{B}{}\ExplSyntaxOff C

\end{document}
```

but instead I get

> A B C 1

and

> A B1C

Why does `\hbox:n` seem to start a new paragraph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the sources (`l3color-base.dtx`)

```
% \begin{macro}{\color_group_begin:, \color_group_end:}
%   Grouping for color is almost the same as using the basic \cs{group_begin:}
%   and \cs{group_end:} functions.  However, in vertical mode the end-of-group
%   needs a \tn{par}, which in horizontal mode does nothing.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\cs_new_eq:NN \color_group_begin: \group_begin:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \color_group_end:
  {
      \par
    \group_end:
  }
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
```

In horizontal mode, we have nothing to worry about with an extra `\par`, so have the same code in all cases.

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have asked the more relevant question of how to get the same output. I want to put 1 at the end of the paragraph but there is a stupid hbox:n in the way

Comment: @StrongBad I think I need an example: the entire point here is that `\par` should be a no-op in horizontal mode ....

Comment: I have asked a new question which provides my actual use case and a new MWE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458507/add-text-at-end-of-paragraph-that-has-an-hboxn